# Linux is loading wrong drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel

I have a lot of problems:

Is there a way to fix some or all of this errors by the Kernel config (**make menuconfig**)?

Hardware: [Acer Aspire 3 (A315-41-R001)](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.GY9AA.004)

Operating system: KDE neon (Ubuntu 18.04)

Linux Kernel version: 4.20.12

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:01.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15db
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15dc
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

**lscpu**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               17
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             1429.807
CPU max MHz:         2000,0000
CPU min MHz:         1600,0000
BogoMIPS:            3992.26
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

I assume that a wrong driver gets loaded.

**lspci -v**

```
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at e0904000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at e0900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

The Ethernet device is a **RTL8111**/8168/8411 and the right driver is available in the Kernel:

```
--- Ethernet driver support

    [ ]   AMD devices
    < >     AMD 8111 (new PCI LANCE) support
    < >     AMD PCnet32 PCI support
    < >     AMD 10GbE Ethernet driver
```

but Linux is loading the  **RealTek R8169**.

```
--- Ethernet driver support
    [*]   Realtek devices
    < >     AT-LAN-TEC/RealTek pocket adapter support
    < >     RealTek RTL-8139 C+ PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter support
    < >     RealTek RTL-8129/8130/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter support
    <M>     Realtek 8169 gigabit ethernet support
```

RealTek may be is the Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM), but AMD have a own driver for this device and maybe this chip is modified for AMD, therefore it needs a special AMD driver.

Same thing whit some other drivers like the **AMD 8111 GPIO driver** is not get loaded.
there are a few 8111 driver which not get loaded like in this case:

```
        *** PC SMBus host controller drivers ***
< > ALI 1535
< > ALI 1563
< > ALI 15x3
< > AMD 756/766/768/8111 and nVidia nForce
< > AMD 8111
< > Intel 82801 (ICH/PCH)
< > Intel SCH SMBus 1.0
< > Intel iSMT SMBus Controller
<M> Intel PIIX4 and compatible (ATI/AMD/Serverworks/Broadcom/SMSC)
```

The original AMD 8111 driver is available but Linux is loading a Intel driver, WHY???

In Hardware Monitoring support also gets the wrong driver loaded, it loads the 10h+ driver but it is the 15h CPU

```
    -- Hardware Monitoring support --

< >   AMD Athlon64/FX or Opteron temperature sensor
<*>   AMD Family 10h+ temperature sensor
< >   AMD Family 15h processor power
```

I believe this is a bug chain, if a wrong driver gets loaded, the following driver also be incorrectly loaded and all starts whit the **IOMMU**

**journalctl -xb**

```
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping


linux kernel: do_IRQ: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #5
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #6
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #7
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 7.55 No irq handler for vector


linux kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q46], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181003/dswload2-316)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181003/psobject-221)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20181003/psloop-543)
linux kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2.BCM5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/dswload2-160)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20181003/psobject-221)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20181003/psobject-604)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20181003/psloop-543)


linux kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x8f7a5000-0x8f7a8fff]


linux kernel: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-129)


linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:   device [1022:15d3] error status/mask=00000080/00006000
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:    [ 7] BadDLLP


linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:   device [1022:15d3] error status/mask=00000040/00006000
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:    [ 6] BadTLP


linux kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:2! type 0 expected 3
linux kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:3! type 0 expected 3


-- Unit systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service has begun starting up.
linux systemd-backlight[645]: Failed to get backlight or LED device'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
linux systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
-- Subject: Unit boot-efi.mount has begun start-up


-- Unit boot-efi.mount has begun starting up.
linux systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
linux systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has failed


-- The start-up result is RESULT.
linux kernel: hid-generic 0003:1241:1503.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.4-2/input0
linux kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
linux kernel: input:   USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1241:1503.0005/input/input20
linux kernel: input:   USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1241:1503.0005/input/input21
linux kernel: hid-generic 0003:1241:1503.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.4-2/input1
linux kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
linux kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514ec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc515a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51490 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc5149c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc515e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514b0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51514 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51540 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 11 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ebc0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ec68 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb50 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb5c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eca8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb70 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb80 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eba8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ebd4 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ec00 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 42 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48fec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49000 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f9c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f90 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49140 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49100 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 29 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49180 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48fec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49000 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f9c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f90 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49140 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49100 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 29 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49180 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc492c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49200 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49280 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc492e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49340 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc493c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49300 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: acpi AMDI0010:01: Already enumerated
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 96 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f26c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f328 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f210 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f21c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f368 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f230 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f268 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f294 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f2c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 86 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f208 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f204 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f280 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c940 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c9e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8d0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8dc flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3ca28 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8f0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c900 flags=0x0020]
linux systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device.device: Job dev-disk-by\xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device.devic
linux systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device has failed


linux wpa_supplicant[827]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
linux wpa_supplicant[827]: dbus: Failed to construct signal


linux spice-vdagent[1258]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0


linux pulseaudio[1244]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono
```

Comment: You can always uncheck the bad drivers, and make the missing ones as modules.

Comment: Are you sure the ethernet chip is an 8111 (and not a 8168)? The AMD8111 is surely NOT in this notebook, as it is from pre-Ryzen times.

Comment: lspci says that it is a AMD 8111 Ethernet device

Comment: Could you re-do the lspci outputs with `-nn` option added?

Comment: i posted **lspci -v -nn** below

Answer (score -1):

**lspci -v -nn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d0]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d1]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Capabilities: [40] Secure device <?>
    Capabilities: [64] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [74] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+

00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:01.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d3] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0900000-e09fffff
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1453]
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:01.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15d3] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: e0200000-e03fffff
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1453]
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15db] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0500000-e08fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000e01fffff
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15dc] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: e0400000-e04fffff
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:0000]
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH SMBus Controller [1025:1259]
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH LPC Bridge [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e8]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e9]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ea]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15eb]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ec]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ed]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ee]
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15ef]
    Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI 
Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader 
[1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at e0905000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at e0910000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci

01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit 
Ethernet Controller [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at e0904000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at e0900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless 
Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network 
Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at e0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15dd] (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at e0800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=3 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:15de]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at e0888000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15df]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at e0700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at e088c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=2 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>

03:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e0] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at e0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e1] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at e0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at e0880000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 61) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] 
[1025:1259]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at e0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
```

Comment: Please do not add an answer which isnt. The appropriate course if action is to edit your question and add the updated information.

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 34016.

Comment: There's other websites to host pasted stuff like this, I think pastebin is one